# Mostrar y ocultar enlaces con hover

Tags: html5, css3

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer un efecto con hover en el cual se oculte un enlace que contiene un botón de contacto. El hecho es que quiero que sea visible dentro del div únicamente cuando se pose el ratón sobre el div padre.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

El *problemilla* de la [respuesta de @Error404](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/43038/6491), es que con `display: none;` te *quita* el espacio que ocupaba el elemento y puedes llegar a tener efectos no deseados, como verás en el próximo ejemplo:

```css
#contenedor{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#boton{
  display: none;
}

#contenedor:hover > #boton{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>OTRO ELEMENTO</p>
    <button id="boton">Estas sobre el div</button>
  <p>OTRO ELEMENTO</p>
</div>
```

El próximo ejemplo es con la propiedad `visibility`, con lo cual ocupa el sitio sin ser visible:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button { 
  visibility: hidden; 
}

div:hover button {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>OTRO ELEMENTO</p>
    <button>Estas sobre el div</button>
  <p>OTRO ELEMENTO</p>
</div>
```

**Info**: No es necesario usar el selector `>` ya que se encuentran dentro del elemento `div#contenedor`.

Answer (score 3):

Para este propósito puedes usar el selector `>` que indica que es un hijo directo del padre para referirte al botón. Posteriormente, cuando haces `hover` en el div puedes hacer que se muestre el botón modificando la propiedad `display`. Por defecto, tendremos que indicar que la propiedad `display` del botón está invisible (`display: none`).

Ejemplo:

```css
#contenedor{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#boton{
  display: none;
}

#contenedor:hover > #boton{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <button id="boton">Estas sobre el div</button>
</div>
```